# Typeform Hidden Parameters

Tags: wordpress, typeform

I need help for the pass hidden parameters of embeded typeform from wordpress page where i have integrated that form.

url : https://admin.typeform.com
I have created form in this site and used this embeded form in to my wordpress page. In that form i set some hidden fields which values i want to pass from wordpress page.

How can i passed that hidden fields value dynamically from wordpress?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PD4Tz.png)

Answer (score 1):

You can assign values to hidden fields by adding them to the typeform URL.

Example:
if you have a hidden field named `first_name` and `age`

Your typeform URL should look like this:

`https://YOUR_DOMAIN.typeform.com/to/YOUR_FORM_ID?first_name=John&age=22`

You can use this URL directly to embed it on Wordpress.

You can read more about hidden fields on an embedded typeform on [Typeform Help Center](https://www.typeform.com/help/use-hidden-fields-embedded-typeforms/).

Comment: Hello i want to pass first_name and age from WordPress Page where I have integrated form. I used this page after checkout so every time order first_name and age will be different. Can you help for that?

Comment: If the URL you are redirecting to has the parameter, you can extract it and pass it to the embed url.
If you have more issues you should probably contact Typeform support directly.